# Javascript compare input to a long .txt file

Tags: javascript

Basically, I'm working on a simple application, that would allow you to click a number and then compare this clicked number to a long sequence in a seperate `.txt` file(basically an application to help learn number PI).

The problem is that I'm not sure how to load `.txt` file into my application.
File contains over `100,000` digits of **PI**.

My HTML looks like this(jQuery Mobile):

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><input class="pi-enter" type="button" value="1"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><input class="pi-enter" type="button" value="2"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><input class="pi-enter" type="button" value="3"></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><input class="pi-enter" type="button" value="4"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><input class="pi-enter" type="button" value="5"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><input class="pi-enter" type="button" value="6"></div>
</fieldset>
 <fieldset class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><input class="pi-enter" type="button" value="7"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><input class="pi-enter" type="button" value="8"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><input class="pi-enter" type="button" value="9"></div>
</fieldset>
```

My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    var PI = pi.txt;
    $('input.pi-enter').click(function(){
        counter++;
        if ($(this).val() !== PI[counter] )
        {
            alert'You made a mistake!');
        }
    });
});
```

When a number is entered I would compare it to a sequence from `.txt` file.

How would I load this long file to a string? Via Ajax or is there (hopefully) a better way?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Are you running any server-side code (PHP or ASP.NET) or is it all HTML and JS files?

Comment: At the moment it's just .js and HTML, but it could use PHP. I guess I would need a server for Ajax if nothing else..

Comment: You could split it into different files, and request them say 1000 characters at a time

Comment: It is a possibility, I was just hoping for a 'cleaner' way of doing it =)

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do it without PHP, in which case you could just make a (This isn't great) ajax request each time, and let PHP figure it out

Comment: A minor issue, but your HTML is missing "0" and ".". If you are looking at emulating the look of a numeric keypad, it's also upside-down.

Comment: @AdrianWragg: Thanks, I was so caught in this 'long-file' problem, that I totally missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url : "pi.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success : function (data) {
        // do your comparison here, data is the file-content
    }
});
```

Of course, pi.txt must be on the server, since you have no access to the filesystem using JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for answer, can I load 100,000 digits to a variable?

Comment: if you use strings for comparison it should work fine. So just convert user input to a string and compare it to the data from the file